# Android Studio Flutter Demo: How to fix Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

Tried to run the Flutter Demo code in main.dart, the emulator is working properly (displaying home screen) but it's not displaying the flutter demo after running it. Instead, there looks like a bunch of error messages in the console. I have copied the error messages below.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:174)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:636)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Have tried:** changing Java version in gradle-wrapper.properties and adding some code in build.gradle and gradle.properties but none of them works. Flutter doctor doesn't have any problem.

**I'm using:** Android Studio Giraffe, Flutter version 3.16.1, Dart version 3.2.1, JDK 17.

I'm not sure if there's incompatibility of the Java version / Gradle, or the emulator has problem. Anyone know how to fix this?

**UPDATE:** I have successfully opened the Flutter Demo by doing a few things. Not sure which one is the solution. If anyone encounter this problem, you may try them out:

1. Delete Android Studio and Flutter. Then, download everything again from the website.
2. Adding Internet Permission at AndroidManefest.xml (open Android Studio > under the project file > AndroidManifest.xml)
3. Connect a different Wi-Fi.
4. Shut down the laptop for a while and open again.

Comment: Did you tried adding Required ```Internet``` Permission In ```AndroidManifest.xml``` file?

Comment: Tried adding <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> to AndroidManifest.xml but still not working. Also, I notice there are a few problem with my AndroidManifest.xml such as Unresolved class '{applicationName}', Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher', Unresolved class 'MainActivity', Cannot resolve symbol '@style/LaunchTheme', Cannot resolve symbol '@style/NormalTheme'.